# Where does だって come from?

Tags: particles, etymology

Does だって find it's roots in some different combination of words, or is it it's own, self made, particle? Where does だって come from?

Comment: Which だって are you referring to?

Comment: I forget the exact context. It was being used at the end of a sentence, and it (may) have been exclamatory?

Comment: It's probably the lesser formal form of だそうです, which translates to xxx said, or apparently..

Comment: It was　A:　いさかさん、子供四人もいるんだって。
B: チャウチャウ、六人や。
I also don't know why they used も。

Comment: I think it's 「だ」(http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/132198/m0u/%E3%81%A0/) + 「って」(http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/147762/m0u/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“だって” is a sentence-ending particle, coming from binding particle “だって”: a sound change of “だとて”, which is an auxiliary verb of assertion “だ” followed by <strike>an auxiliary verb</strike> a binding particle “とて”, and it is used in a casual conversation.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong but is とて an auxiliary verb/助動詞? Isn't it a (quotative case) particle/助詞?

Comment: @Anthony: I have to admit, I'd never heard of とて but thanks to Chocolate and Shun I can see it exists in my dictionary but I am still not sure understand this particle.  Perhaps you should revise your question to ask about the use of とて as in だとてー＞だって, where it comes from and how it works?  I've never seen it mentioned in a text book or class.

Comment: @Chocolate, thanks for pointing. とて is a binding particle(係助詞), not an auxiliary verb. I corrected my answer!

Comment: @Tim, should I explain means and usage examples here?